# How to get value of argument in with getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

```
while getopts ':s:e:ci:z:n:d:m:' opt; do
  echo -- $opt
  echo -- $OPTORG
done
```

For The above snippet when executed with

`bash a.sh -c -m lsdjfe -s "all ab" -d all`

Results into

```
-- c
--
-- m
--
-- s
--
-- d
--
```

Where as i was expecting

```
-- c
--
-- m
-- lsdjfe
-- s
-- all ab
-- d
-- all
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: OPTARG, not OPTORG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one character was wrong. This is the corrected version:

```
while getopts ':s:e:ci:z:n:d:m:' opt; do
  echo -- $opt
  echo -- $OPTARG
done
```

You misspelled `OPTARG` as `OPTORG`.